# Every system TinCan Conformant is necessarily SCORM conformant?

Tags: scorm, standards-compliance, tin-can-api

As TinCan is an upgrade of SCORM, can we consider the following as a fact:
A system (LMS) that accepts TinCan objects should necessarily accept SCORM Objects? and If so, do we necessarily loose the tracking ability in this case, or we could configure SCORM's javascript to target an external LRS with tracking data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Tin Can (officially named the [Experience API](https://www.adlnet.gov/adl-research/performance-tracking-analysis/experience-api/)) and SCORM are two unrelated standards. They are only related in ownership (ADL) and audience (e-learning developers).

Tin Can was designed for developers who were frustrated with the limitations of SCORM, including the requirement for the content to be hosted in an LMS. Tin Can does not require content to be hosted in an LMS.

Some Tin Can-based courses use SCORM-style statements for compatibility and interoperability ([documentation](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-SCORM-Profile/blob/master/xapi-scorm-profile.md)), but there is no requirement for an LMS that supports SCORM to support Tin Can, or an Learning Record Store (LRS) that supports Tin Can to support SCORM.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer,
Supposing you are building an LMS, where you will launch content you will (mainly) create. will you just support TinCan, or you may care about the old version SCORM and support it also? 
and on the other hand, supposing that you are building an external LRS, is it doable to track data sent by SCORM Pkg in the same way you are tracking TinCan Pkgs? or forgetting about SCORM is better?!

Comment: SCORM is difficult to implement, especially when building an LMS. I would guess that Tin Can is easier. There are open-source LMSs which support SCORM (the most popular is Moodle), and open-source LRSs for Tin Can (eg Learning Locker). I'd take a look at their codebases and see which one suits you better. If you're not worried about importing other peoples' courses, go with whichever one is easier for you. Bear in mind Tin Can allows you to accept data from external sources, not just courses hosted in the LMS, so it offers much more flexibility.

Comment: If you want traditional looking e-learning import, launch and tracking using Tin Can as the "plumbing" you should take a look at cmi5. It is still *very* early in adoption but is designed for this specific use case. http://experienceapi.com/cmi5